# Mysql Remove 0 and add 353 in contact numbers

Tags: mysql

i have alot of numbers with 10 digits like this

0987654321

I want a sql query that will remove the 0 and add 353.

i only want to do it for 10 digit numbers

Is there any body that can help me with this please?

Comment: And is that only for the first digit? or 0 at any position??

Comment: By "add 353", did you that mean you want to perform an addition operation, so the result should be 987654674? Or were you meaning that you wanted to perform string manipulation, to append '353' onto to the end of the string, or did you want to prepend '353' to the beginning of the string? Is it only the digit zero at the beginnng of the string you want to remove, or any leading digit? What if there are two or more leading zeros, do you want remove just the first one? If you can be more specific about what it is you are needing to achieve, you will be that much closer to actually achieving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression to check the length.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    `your_column_name`, 
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(`your_column_name`) = 10 
    AND LEFT(`your_column_name`, 1) = '0'
        THEN CONCAT('353', RIGHT(`your_column_name`, 9))
        ELSE `your_column_name` END as `new_column_name`
FROM `your_table_name`;
```

Or if you want to update that particular column. Then

**Query**

```
UPDATE `your_table_name`
SET `your_column_name` = CONCAT('353', RIGHT(`your_column_name`, 9))
WHERE LENGTH(`your_column_name`) = 10
AND LEFT(`your_column_name`, 1) = '0';
```

Comment: in case of a select, the CASE is correct, but why invoke calculation if SUBSTRING is perfect here? Also, why would you want to update all rows? That would set the value to exactly the original if the length was not 10 and would - if existent - update timestamps without a real change in values.

Comment: @FlorianHeer : Yeah, for updation we can use the where condition.

Comment: Still, why "RIGHT(..., LENGTH() -1)"? SUBSTRING(...,2) produces the same result, yet is simpler.

Comment: @FlorianHeer : I have updated. Anyway we are checking for length of 10. Condition is update for length = 10 and first character = 0. So we need the last 9 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET column = CONCAT('353', SUBSTRING(column, 2)) 
WHERE LENGTH(column) = 10;
```

This sets the contents of the column 'column' to 353 + <original string, without first character>, for all and only those that have 10 characters.